# Prove a group generated by a,b is of order 16

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that the group generated by generators $a,b$  and relations $a^8=b^2 a^4 = ab^{-1}ab = e$ has order less than or equal to 16.  ( In fact, one can show it is isomorphic to the Klein 4-group, $Z_2 \times Z_2$.)

Let $G=<a,b| a^8=b^2 a^4 = ab^{-1}ab = e>.$ By this relations, we have $$ab=ba^{-1}=a^{-1}b$$ and $a^{4}=b^{-2}$, so $|b^{-1}|=4=|b| $ which implies $|b|=|b^{-1}|=4.$

I dont know how to find a way from here to show that. I would appreciate any help or hint

Comment: So we have $ab=a^{-1}b$?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $(b^2a^4)^2 = b^4a^8 = e$. The order of $b$ must divide $4$. If $|b| = 4$ then $b^2 = a^{-4}$. So we can write $G =\{a^i b^j : 0 \leq i < 8, 0 \leq j < 2\}$.

If $|b| = 2$, then we can still write $G = \{a^i b^j : 0 \leq i < 8, 0 \leq j < 2\}$

Either way, this set has at most size 16.

Comment: $b^2=a^4\not\Longrightarrow b=a^2$. For example, consider two distinct transpositions.

Comment: What is the order of $b$ then, is it 4? it is why we take $0 \leq j \leq 1?$

Comment: If $b=a^2$, the problem is trivial. Group generated by $a$ and $b$ is simply the cyclic group generated by $a$, having order atmost $8$.

Comment: @Martund  this should fix the error. $|b|$ is at most 4, so we can consider the two cases separately

Answer (score 0):

Let $G=<a,b| a^8=b^2 a^4 = ab^{-1}ab = e>.$ By this relations, we have $$ab=ba^{-1}=a^{-1}b \Rightarrow a=a^{-1}, $$ so $G$ is an abelian group. Also $$a^8=b^2a^4, \Rightarrow a^4=b^2$$
so $|b|=4$. So we have $G=\{a^ib^j: 1 \leq i \leq 8, \ 0 \leq j \leq 1 \}.$ Hence this group $G$ can have at most 16 distinct elements. Next consider $H=<a>$, then $$H=\{e,a,a^2,a^3,a^4,a^5,a^6,a^7\}=\{e,a,\}$$
Note that since $G$ abelian and $ab^{-1}ab=e$, then $a^2=e.$ So $a^2=a^4=a^6=e$ and $a=a^3=a^5=a^7$, so $$H=<a>=\{e,a\} \cong Z_2$$
Also, for $M=<b>$, $M=\{e,b\}$, so $M \cong Z_2.$ Hence $H \times M \cong Z_2 \times Z_2.$
To show $G \cong Z_2 \times Z_2$ it suffices to show that $G \cong H \times M.$ To see that $G \cong H \times K$, we will show $HM=G$. Clearly $HM \subseteq G$. Let $x \in G$ then $x=a^ib^j$ where $1 \leq i \leq 8,\ 0\leq j \leq 1$. We have here two cases:\
(i) $x=a^i$. Since $H=<a>=\{e,a\}$, then $a_i$ either equals $e$ or $a$ and hence in $HM$.\
(i) $x=a^ib$. Either $a^ib=b$ or $a^ib=ab $ and hence in $HM$, so $G \subseteq HM$. Therefore, by defining $\psi: H \times M \rightarrow G$ by $ \psi(x,y)=xy$ we see that $\psi$ is a group homomorphism that is bijection, so $G \cong H \times M \cong Z_2 \times Z_2.$